# How would I go about combining these tables?

Tags: mysql

I know lots about MySQL, but there are some things that I just can't do. I have information stored in 2 tables for my game.

1. `user_data`:

   - `Name` (VARCHAR)
   - `Money` (INT)
   - `Times Played` (INT)
2. `kill_events` (A new row is inserted on every kill):

   - `killer` (VARCHAR)
   - `victim` (VARCHAR)
   - `time` (DATETIME)

I need a query that will combine these tables into a table like this:

- `name` (VARCHAR)
- `money` (INT)
- `kills` (INT)  (the number of times they are the `killer` in the `kill_events` table)
- `deaths` (INT) (the number of times they are the `victim` in the `kill_events` table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways that one could achieve this.  One option would be:

```
SELECT   u.name,
         u.money,
         IFNULL(SUM(u.name = e.killer), 0) AS kills,
         IFNULL(SUM(u.name = e.victim), 0) AS deaths
FROM     user_data AS u LEFT JOIN kill_events AS e
      ON u.name IN (e.killer, e.victim)
GROUP BY u.name
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. There is one problem though. If they have never had a kill or died then it returns as null. How would I go about setting the default to 0 if they have never had a kill?